# Передача std::string в шаблонную функцию класса

Tags: c++, sqlite, шаблоны-с++

Пишу обертку на C++ над Си-шной библиотекой sqlite.
Вот есть у меня класс Statement. В нем реализованы методы setParam для int, double, blob, std::string и NULL:

```
 void setParam(int pos, const void * val, size_t size);
 void setParam(const std::string & name, const void * val, size_t size);
 void setParam(int pos, const double val);
 void setParam(const std::string & name, const double val);
 void setParam(int pos, const int val);
 void setParam(const std::string & name, const int val);
 void setParam(int pos, const std::string & val);
 void setParam(const std::string & name, const std::string & val);
```

Как можно видеть, привязка параметра есть как по индексу, так и по имени параметра.
Но я также хочу реализовать возможность привязки к запросу объекта любого класса,
с предоставлением функции преобразования этого объекта к int, double, string или blob.
Как по индексу параметра:

```
 template<typename From, typename To>
 void setParam(int pos, const From & val, Converter<From, To> converter)
 {
   setParam(pos, converter(val));
 }

 Statement stmt(db, "SELECT * FROM artists WHERE ArtistId = ?;");
 stmt.setParam(1, bpt::second_clock::universal_time(), bpt::to_iso_extended_string);
```

Здесь Converter это просто

```
template<typename From, typename To>
using Converter = std::function<To(From)>;
```

И это прекрасно работает.
НО!!
Если я сделаю такой же шаблон, но для привязки параметра по имени:

```
template<typename From, typename To>
void setParam(std::string name, const From & val, Converter<From, To> converter)
{
  setParam<From, To>(bindParameterIndex(name), val, converter);
}
```

то при компиляции следующего кода:

```
Statement stmt(db, "SELECT * FROM artists WHERE ArtistId = :val;");
stmt.setParam("val", bpt::second_clock::universal_time(), bpt::to_iso_extended_string);
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
    error: no matching function for call to 'sqlitelib::Statement::setParam(const char [4],     boost::posix_time::ptime, std::__cxx11::string (&)(boost::posix_time::ptime))'
   stmt.setParam("val", bpt::second_clock::universal_time(), bpt::to_iso_extended_string);
```

Я не силен в шаблонах, и не понимаю, почему здесь std::string низводится до const char[4], а также не знаю как это предотвратить. Просьба, помочь в решении проблемы. Заранее благодарен

Я пробовал передавать строку по значению, а не по ссылке. Результата нет

Answer (score 0):

```
"val" == {'v', 'a', 'l', \0};
```

В классе `std::string` есть метод `c_str()`, который возвращает указатель на первый символ строки, представленный как массив символов типа `char`. Если вы передадите name.`c_str()` в функцию, она будет ожидать аргумент типа `const char*`, который будет указывать на начало строки `"val"` в памяти.

Если вы получаете `const char[4]` вместо объекта `std::string`, то возможно, что в функции, которая принимает аргумент `const string &name`, **name** было передано как C-строка, используя метод `c_str()`.

есть еще `name.data()` - возвращает non-const массив.

Comment: Но это не решит проблему. Если я передам в метод не name.c_str(), а литерал строки, то получу такую же ошибку компиляции

Comment: @vlad_us, то есть вы уже пытались объявить допустим просто такую функцию для теста: setParam(const char [4],     boost::posix_time::ptime, std::__cxx11::string (&)(boost::posix_time::ptime))?

Comment: да, вот такая функция:
void setParam(
    const char name[4],
    const boost::posix_time::ptime & val,
    std::string(&converter)(boost::posix_time::ptime))
{
    setParam(std::string(name), converter(val));
}

работает для вызова:
stmt.setParam("val", bpt::second_clock::universal_time(), bpt::to_iso_extended_string);

Comment: @vlad_us, но вы хотите передавать именно строку, может если не работает поставите обертку и будете писать дальше(обертку для размера строки).
функция для размера + функция для возврата строки.

функция выглядит нормально, но проблема с конвертацией типа, просто на референс плюсовый нужно зайти и поискать.

как бы вы сейчас целый день убьете на задачу, поставьте лучше обертку и делайте дальше, рано или поздно ответ найдете.